# Getting 502 Bad Gateway while running the Django application within a docker container?

Tags: django, docker

Those are the following steps I am following to run my application within a docker container .

```
docker run -i -t -d -p 8000:8000 c4ba9ec8e613 /bin/bash
docker attach c4ba9ec8e613
```

my start up script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#activate virtual env
echo Activate vitualenv.
source /home/my_env/bin/activate

#restart nginx
echo Restarting Nginx
service nginx restart

# Start Gunicorn processes
echo Starting Gunicorn.
gunicorn OPC.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --daemon
```

This setup is working fine in the local machine but not working within the docker .

Comment: gunicorn is bound to port 800 `--bind=0.0.0.0:800` maybe try `--bind=0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Sorry its 8000 only .

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the port no application to be accessible as my nginx server is responding at port 80

```
docker run -i -t -d -p 80:80 c4ba9ec8e613 /bin/bash
docker attach c4ba9ec8e613
```